# What good is ground meat?

Tags: dungeons-of-dredmor

The ingot grinder can ground up cheese to make grated cheese (which can then be used for making an omelet).  The grinder can also make ground meat which appears to just reduce the quality of the meat.  Are there any recipes or cooking options to make this back into a better food product?

Comment: Doesn't seem like it. I was kinda hoping you could make a little man out of it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Ground Meat / Ground Cheese heals 3 each, and you get several per grinding, so in some cases when grinding up the lower quality foods, you'll end up with a net gain in healing food. Offal heals 3, grinding it up produces food that heals for a total of 6, albeit it in two actions.

Since it stacks, it can also be useful when you're running low on inventory space, you can combine all your meat and cheese into two stacks.

As far as I am aware, they aren't used in any recipes.

EDIT: Also, now that I think of it, it would enable you to create more lutefisk using the horadric lutefisk box. Since you get a minimum of 1 lutefisk per item, grinding the meat and cheese would enable you to get more lutefisk out of meat and cheese items.

Comment: Good point about stacking and low value grinding.  I was kind of hoping to somehow make a cheeseburger or the like with it though (like the cheese omelet, but meaty).

Comment: i liked the idea on grinding for more lutefisk. everybody loves more lutefisk